# How to throw argument in RTK Query (queryFn)

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I have queryFn query in RTK, and I need to get some data from firebase DB by element ID. But when I give this arg to queryFn like in example below, I got undefined.

[image]

and I'm calling it like this:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share also the code as well as the screenshot, in order us to copy the code and give the response easily.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you got `undefined` is because the `useGetCardByIdQuery` hook returns the data undefined initially. The data is going to be available after a success fetch.

As far I understand from your code, you are trying to get **the cards of authorized firebase user**; so you don't need to pass any `id` indeed since I see that you are not using the `id` in the `queryFn`.

In that case, just pass the `undefined` like `useGetCardByIdQuery(undefined);` and return the `cardList`.

And for better typing, you can define the builder query with <OutputType, InputType>

```
getCardsById: builder.query<CardList, string>({
  queryFn: async (id, api, extraOptions, fetchWithBQ) => {
    try {
      const user = getAuth();
      ...
      const cardList = cardSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())

      return { data: cardList }
    } catch (error) {
      return { error }
    }
  },
})
```

Then you can call the hook in the component.

```
const response = useGetCardsByIdQuery(undefined);

if (response.data) {
  const cards = response.data;
  console.log(cards);
}
```